# Remove a polyLine from the mapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, polyline

I've read many posts about it and still i have a problem.
This is my code to draw a polyLine between two points:

```
-(void) drawAline:(CLLocation*)newLocation
{
//drawing a line
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.jerusalem.coordinate.latitude, self.jerusalem.coordinate.longitude);

self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]];
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];

}

-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
if(overlay == self.routeLine)
{
    if(nil == self.routeLineView)
    {
        self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
        self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;
    }
    return self.routeLineView;
}

return nil;
```

}

thats works fine.
The problem is to remove the line.
The next code doesn't work:

```
    for (id<MKOverlay> overlayToRemove in self.mapView.overlays)
{
    if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[MKPolylineView class]])
    {
        [mapView removeOverlay:overlayToRemove];
    }
}
```

the next code doesn't work neither:

```
     if (self.routeLine)
{
[self.mapView removeOverlay:self.routeLine];
    self.routeLineView = nil;
    self.routeLine = nil;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the code that loops through the map view's `overlays` array, this line is the problem:

```
if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[MKPolylineView class]])
```

The map view's `overlays` array contains objects of type `id<MKOverlay>` (the for-loop correctly declares `overlayToRemove` as such).

So the `overlays` array contains the *model* objects for the overlays and not the *views*.

The `MKPolylineView` class is the *view* for an `MKPolyline` overlay *model*.

So the `if` condition should be:

```
if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
```

Note that such a loop will remove *all* polylines from the map.  If you wanted to delete specific polylines, you could set the `title` on each one when adding it and then check it before removing.

The second piece of code that checks and deletes `self.routeLine` directly should work as long as `self.routeLine` is not `nil` and contains a valid reference to an overlay currently on the map.

If you have only a single overlay on the map (the one polyline), you could also just call `removeOverlays` to delete all overlays from the map (whatever they are):

```
[self.mapView removeOverlays:self.mapView.overlays];
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another problem, maybe you could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763469/

Answer (score 2):

Your overlay is a `MKPolyline` the `MKPolylineView` is just how the overlay is displayed when the map is zoomed or scrolled so that the overlay's data shows in the window. The map view's `overlays` array contains the data that will be used to generate the overlay views. There are no views in the `overlays` array. So, to make your code work, change this line

```
if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[MKPolylineView class]])
```

to

```
if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
```

in your third snippet and you will be fine

Comment: @user1553961 one help in Mkmapkit. how can i draw a line between 2 points on ios map using overlayer. please help me.

Comment: @user1553961 i have one code but it is not working for me. could u help me what am did wrong in my code?